# Open and Close jQuery Overlay with Same Element

Tags: jquery, overlay, toggle, switch-statement

I'm currently using a jQuery Tools overlay to fade in an overlay on my website.

Here's the overlay's HTML:

```
<div id="contact">..div content..</div>
```

Here's the element I'm using to open the overlay:

```
<span rel="#contact"></span>
```

Here's the jQuery I'm using for the overlay:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {$("span[rel]").overlay();
    }
);
```

When I click the span with `rel="#contact"`, the div with `id="contact"` fades in. I want to know how to click the same span with `rel="#contact"` again to close the element.

Answer (score 1):

look at [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Thank you! This looks perfect but I don't think I understand how to write it out in my case. Do you think you could show me an example that would work?